# Ordering is not working for string numerical values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sql-order-by

I have a text field(Django) for the amount in the DB like

```
amount = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

SQL query

```
select id, amount from payment order by amount asc;

  id   | amount  |
-------+---------+
 12359 | 1111111 |  ----> entered as "1111111" i.e a string value             
 12360 | 122222  |               
 12342 | 20      |               
 12361 | 222222  |               
 12364 | 2222222 |               
 12362 | 2222222 |               
 12290 | 260.00  |               
 12291 | 260.00  |               
 12292 | 260.00  |               
 12336 | 32      |               
 12363 | 3333333 |               
 12337 | 355     |                
 12331 | 45      |               
 12341 | 740     |             
 12343 | 741     |
```

Problem - Ordering is not working as expected.

Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: For strings, yes this is expected behaviour. But why are you storing numbers as strings? That's a huge mistake to begin with

Answer (score 0):

When you use string, the ordering is based on ASCII based system.
To mitigate this type of issues, it is better to use `models.DecimalField`.

More on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

Answer (score 0):

**amount field** should be **numeric field** not ***text field***. Then Ordering will work.

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Payment(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Please run **migration** after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
select * from tab_name order by column_name::integer;
```

```
 select * from tab_name order by cast(column_name AS integer);
```

```
select * from tab_name order by int8 (column_name);
```

I hope help you.
But I don't get how why you keep yout integer in text or varchar. Later this make lot of issues for you, by space and speed.

Comment: `260.00` can't be cast to an integer

Answer (score 0):

You can [`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) the value as Float field and order by it:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(as_float=Cast('amount', FloatField())).order_by('as_float')
```

But, as @IqbalHussain mentioned in his answer, it is better to change the model.

Comment: Float is one the worst possible datatypes, the starting point of many new problems.